# JSONArray to String[]?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, arrays

how do get string array from JSONArray ?

```
String[] d;

protected void parseJsonString(ArrayList<String[]> deptList,String json){
        try {
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(json);
            int dl = array.length();
            System.out.println(dl);

            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                d[i] = array.getString(i);

            }
            deptList.add(d);
            for (String e : d) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I debuging this code and I get an error NullPointerException here:

```
d[i] = array.getString(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot

```
String[] d = new String[array.length];
```

So String array d is never initialised.. and you try it access its 1st element saying **d[i]**

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize your string array:

```
int dl = array.length();
System.out.println(dl); 
String[] d = new String[dl];
```